# submit only few textarea from multiple textarea fields

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have multiple textarea fields

1. only two textarea can be submitted from multiple textarea field but it is not working
   here is my code.

```js
function draftSave() {
alert("i'm clicked");
if($('.checking-length').length > 2) {
          alert(' You can submit only any two textarea fields');
          return false;
        }
   var one = $('#one').val();
        var two        = $('#two').val();
        var three     = $('#three').val();
        var four    = $('#four').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url('index.php); ?>",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                one: one,
                two: two,
                three: three,
                four : four
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.check.form_status==false){
                    if(!alert("SOMETHING WENT WRONG")){window.location.reload();}
                }else if(data.check.form_status==true){
                    if(!alert("SUBMITTED.!")){window.location.reload();}
                }
            }
        });
}
```

```html
<form>
<textarea rows="2" class="form-control checking-length" name="one" id="one" required maxlength="3500" onKeyup="textareacount3500_characters('one')" placeholder="Your answer.."></textarea>

<textarea rows="2" class="form-control checking-length" name="two" id="two" required maxlength="3500" onKeyup="textareacount3500_characters('two')" placeholder="Your answer.."></textarea>

<textarea rows="2" class="form-control checking-length" name="three" id="three" required maxlength="3500" onKeyup="textareacount3500_characters('three')" placeholder="Your answer.."></textarea>

<textarea rows="2" class="form-control checking-length" name="four" id="four" required maxlength="3500" onKeyup="textareacount3500_characters('four')" placeholder="Your answer.."></textarea>
<a class="btn btn-info waves-effect" name="step5" id="step5" onclick="draftSave()">Draft Save</a>
</form>
```

Here is my code,
There is four textarea fields user have to submit only two textarea fields only from them.
if any two textarea field already filled and user trying to field third textarea field among them then he should get aleart message like you can submit only two textarea field and return false.
I have used the length but not working.

Comment: Please include the rest of the code that is needed to make your example work. It doesn't run, it looks like it's missing at least one js function

Comment: @FluffyKitten Yes, I have updated please have a look once. thanks

Comment: Thanks for updating, but it still doesn't run - we are still missing the `textareacount3500_characters` function. Does this affect what you are trying to do, and can you add that in so we see what it does please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are counting *all* text areas with this code:

```
$('.checking-length').length > 2
```

To count just the filled-in text areas, you can do it as follows:

**1.** Select all the text areas with the `checking-length` class: `$('textarea.checking-length')`...

**2.** ...and filter these to get only the ones that are filled in:

```
.filter(function (i, inputToCheck) { return inputToCheck.value.length > 0; });`
```

This uses an inline function in the `filter` method that checks each textarea, and if it has content it returns true, which adds it to the filtered array...

**3.** ...and we save the filtered array in a variable called e.g. `filledIn`

When we put this together, we get

```
var filledIn = $('textarea.checking-length')
               .filter( function (i, inputToCheck) { return inputToCheck.value.length > 0; });
```

**4.** Now we just need to check the length of our `filledIn` elements, and if it is more than 2, you can do your alert and return false to stop the processing, or if there are <= 2 do whatever you need:

```
if (filledIn.length > 2) {
  alert(' You can submit only any two textarea fields');
  return false;
}
```

**Working Example:** Putting all this together you can see it working here:

```js
function draftSave() {

  /* get all elements with "checking-length" class and 
     filter them using our checkFilledIn function to get only the ones that are filled in */
  var filledIn = $('textarea.checking-length')
                 .filter(function (i, inputToCheck) { return inputToCheck.value.length > 0; });

  /* if there are more than 2 filled in, alert and stop processing */
  if (filledIn.length > 2) {
    alert(' You can submit only any two textarea fields');
    return false;
  }
  /* Otherwise do whatever you need to do...*/
  console.log("Saving...");
}

function textareacount3500_characters() { /*whatever goes here... */ }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form>
<textarea rows="2" class="form-control checking-length" name="one" id="one" required maxlength="3500" onKeyup="textareacount3500_characters('one')" placeholder="Your answer.."></textarea>

<textarea rows="2" class="form-control checking-length" name="two" id="two" required maxlength="3500" onKeyup="textareacount3500_characters('two')" placeholder="Your answer.."></textarea>

<textarea rows="2" class="form-control checking-length" name="three" id="three" required maxlength="3500" onKeyup="textareacount3500_characters('three')" placeholder="Your answer.."></textarea>

<textarea rows="2" class="form-control checking-length" name="four" id="four" required maxlength="3500" onKeyup="textareacount3500_characters('four')" placeholder="Your answer.."></textarea>
<a class="btn btn-info waves-effect" name="step5" id="step5" onclick="draftSave()">Draft Save</a>
</form>
```

Comment: @mdserver Glad to help! But I'm not a bro, I'm female :)

Answer (score 1):

Might be more user-friendly to make the other textareas `disabled` if 2 have been filled out:

```js
const $textareas = $('textarea');
$textareas.on('keyup', () => {
  const filledCount = $textareas.filter((_, textarea) => textarea.value).length;
  if (filledCount === 2) {
    // Disable empty textareas:
    $textareas.filter((_, textarea) => !textarea.value).prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $textareas.prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <textarea rows="2" class="form-control checking-length" name="one" id="one" required maxlength="3500" placeholder="Your answer.."></textarea>

  <textarea rows="2" class="form-control checking-length" name="two" id="two" required maxlength="3500" placeholder="Your answer.."></textarea>

  <textarea rows="2" class="form-control checking-length" name="three" id="three" required maxlength="3500" placeholder="Your answer.."></textarea>

  <textarea rows="2" class="form-control checking-length" name="four" id="four" required maxlength="3500" placeholder="Your answer.."></textarea>
  <a class="btn btn-info waves-effect" name="step5" id="step5" onclick="draftSave()">Draft Save</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Its worked fine but im expecting like if there is any two field already filled and user tried to filled three and as well four also so after clicking on draft save then he should receive alert with msg like you can submit only two textarea field only.